# Android 4.2.2 app incompatibility

Tags: android, google-play, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Ok, Like honestly where do I even begin trying to figure out why my app isn't compatible on 4.2.2 devices and how to make it so?

Where do I start?

I assumed using this ...

```
        <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

was good enough.

Just getting an app on the market and fixing all the itty bitty problems is heroic, now another one pops up.

Is there a way to check all the methods I'm using against a db or list, to make sure they are 4.2.2 compatible?

The app runs fine if I side load it on a 4.2.2 device, but those devices can't access it from the market.

Can anyone shed some light?

btw this is happening on an emulator with google play market installed, I haven't had a actual 4.2.2 device search for the app on the play market. maybe this is isolated to the emulator...

Comment: have you made it available to all the devices?

Comment: this is the first time I'm hearing about this option...how so? OOO you mean in the console? yes! let me double check

Comment: You can see whether a class/method is compatible by choosing the minimum Sdk version in the Android Document Reference (on the left side you should see the API level. It greys out all incompatible references) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

some things you can check:

1. in the "project.properties" file, make sure it has :

   target=android-17
2. make sure you have the latest ADT & SDK before exporting the app, and also make sure (as you've written) that you have in the manifest (above the application tag) :

   > ```
   > <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   > ```
3. in the manifest file, make sure you have

   > ```
   > <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
   > android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
   > android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
   > ```
4. in the developer console, make sure no device is excluded.
5. all of the above should be set at least for the app project . for libraries, you should do it too, but it's less important.